# Constructor Methods

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

It seems to me that there is a certain kind of method that we should be able to declare. Something to the effect of 'Constructor Method' or 'Constructor Helper'.

These would be methods that can only be called from constructors. There are a few reasons I can see for doing this:

- First, I like my constructors to be clean. If I have to dump a lot of logic into a constructor, I would like to organize it. But then, the methods that I organize that logic into are probably not methods that I should ever call outside of a constructor. I would like to be able to declare constructor-only methods.
- Secondly and similarly, readonly member variables can only be initialized inside a constructor. You can't, for example, initialize a readonly variable in a method, even if you call that method from a constructor. I would like to be able to declare the method 'constructor-only', and then I would be able to initialize read only member variables in it.
- Lastly, while I can see the argument that '*if your constructors are complex enough to need to be reduced to multiple method calls, you're doing too much in them*', there is the case of having more than one constructor that might need the exact same logic as another. If I have three constructors that all need to initialize a readonly member variable, I should pull that initialization logic into a separate method. While I could set up such a method that returns the initialization value, as opposed to actually doing the initialization, I still would like to be able to declare such a method as 'constructor-only', since it probably shouldn't be used anywhere else.

EDIT: Turning this into a question: are there problems that I'm not aware of with this idea, is it unnecessary, or could this actually be a useful feature?

Thanks

Comment: Discussions like this are welcome on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ - not here.

Comment: They are called *private methods*.

Comment: @Hans: Private methods can't write to `initonly` variables (C# keyword `readonly`)...

Comment: This seems to be a CLR question, not C#.  `initonly` is enforced by the runtime.

Comment: *So what's the question?* reworded as question. *They are called private methods*. as Ben said, private methods can't write to readonly variables. Also private methods can be called in a regular context. These methods would only make sense in a constructor context.

Comment: I guess this is not really a discussion forum, but a problem solving site? Is there some place here that I should post something like this, or is this kind of thing just not something to post on stackoverflow?

Comment: @Sahuagin: Discussion certainly do happen here, but it's best when the question is objective -- that is, it has a single answer which is provably right.  I'm not sure this would fit well over on programmers.se, it really is a language design question.  I'll vote for reopening, but this is a bit on the subjective side.

Comment: I believe that not only can helper methods return a value, which the constructor assigned to the `initonly` variable, but the constructor should be able to pass `initonly` variables by reference to a helper method which receives them as `out` parameters.  This overcomes the "one return value per helper method" limitation.

Comment: @Ben ***it's best when the question is objective -- that is, it has a single answer which is provably right.*** k, that makes sense. ***This overcomes the "one return value per helper method" limitation*** that kind of thing is what I have concluded is best for now. it's just that I would like methods like that to be prevented from being called from a regular method in the same way that you can't call a constructor from a regular method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you said in your last point. Having lot of logic in constructor is somehow wrong. At least for me. You should either do it somewhere else or don't do it at all. Something like creating separate class that doest this and then pass this class as parameter into constuctor.

And if your want to generalize constructor calls, you can chain different constructors, so when one is called, another is called too along with separate logic in the first one. Then some of those constructors can be private, so they cannot be called from outside.

Comment: As far as I can see all the points he stated can be covered by private constructors and delegating via this() or base()

Comment: constructors can't repeat signatures. I can't make three parameterless constructors for example.